# Create list of characters seperated by space from string

Tags: python-3.x

```
def word_parser(string):
    stringList=[]
    index=string.isspace()
    for i in range(len(string)):
        stringList.append(string[i:index]
    return stringList
```

my function needs to create a list of characters that are separated by spaces in a string but I cant use split. How can I edit my code? (Ex."Hello World" = ['Hello','World'])

Answer (score 0):

```
def word_parser(string):
    string = string.strip()
    indices = [_ for _ in range(len(string)) if string[_].isspace()]
    indices.append(len(string))
    indices.insert(0,-1)
    return [string[indices[_-1]:indices[_]] for _ in range(1,len(indices))]
```